# Publish content to Broker

Tags: publishing, cme

I have an issue with the publication of content to Tridion Broker database. I had a configuration in my `cd_storage` that only "publish" content to local file system, but I would like to publish this content in Tridion Broker database too in order to use it with XPM.

The publish transaction finishes ok, but when I go to the database to review it, I don´t find any content in the `ITEMS` table or `PAGE` table.

This is my `cd_storage_conf` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="C:\Publicaciones" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
                <Root Path="C:\Publicaciones\data" />
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFile" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\config\cd_licenses.xml"/>        
</Configuration>
```

Note that I have commented the part of JNDI, because I don´t know what is the correct configuration:

```
<!-- Configuration example for using a MS SQL based JNDI datasource.
    <Storage Type="persistence" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" dialect="MSSQL" Id="defaultdb5" JNDIName="java:comp/env/jdbc/NAME_SERVER_NETOSONE/Tridion_Broker"/>-->
```

If I uncomment this lines, I get the following error:

> Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-63-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. 
>   at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       ... 9 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultdb5DataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at com.tridion.storage.util.EntityManagerFactoryBeanConfigurer.configure(EntityManagerFactoryBeanConfigurer.java:55) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configureDatasource(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:87) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configure(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:44) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:26) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:113) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       ... 22 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]

I'm using the sqljdbc4 driver (I have 1.8.0_131 java version), and I have configured a Deployer as Windows Service in the same server as the Content Manager Web App.

Is anyone aware of this issue?

Comment: Can you put the complete cd_storage_conf.xml file? Also specify versions, please

Answer (score 4):

You don't have anything puiblished in the database, because you haven't configured it to publish to it.
You have to indicate

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
```

to indicate that the metadata is published to the database.

You don'f have to use JNDI unless you configure it, and you can use the jdbc driver you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much Raúl. With this modification in cd_storage_conf file the publication to the Content Data Store works fine!

Comment: @netosone if the answer is helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it, see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more details